# How can I pass arguments to the executable in nodemon (or node-supervisor)?

Tags: node.js, debugging, coffeescript, nodemon, node-supervisor

node can be run with a debug parameter like this

```
$ node --debug src/file.js
```

I can also pass that parameter through the coffee-script binary like this

```
$ coffee --nodejs --debug src/file.coffee
```

Which works. But things get more difficult when I involve [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor). Running coffee scripts is no problem:

```
$ supervisor -w src src/file.coffee
```

But I want to debug the coffee scripts that I'm running with [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor). How can I send arguments such as `--debug` through [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)? I tried setting the executable to a string with the arguments like this:

```
$ supervisor -w src -x "coffee --nodejs --debug" src/server.coffee
```

Which produced an infinitely repeating error message saying

> ```
> DEBUG: Starting child process with 'coffee --nodejs --debug src/server.coffee'
> DEBUG: execvp(): No such file or directory
> ```

Which is odd, because running `coffee --nodejs --debug src/server.coffee` in the terminal works.

**So how can I send arguments through [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)?**

---

***Edit:*** I want to expand my question with mentioning that I've now tried using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) as well. It seems [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) is considered preferable to [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor), so I'll accept any answer that explains how to pass `--debug` to the node process when launching coffee scripts through [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

---

***Edit:*** Here's the output from [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon). Clearly the arguments are not passed in the same order :-(

```
$ nodemon -w src -x coffee --nodejs --debug src/server.coffee
15 Jan 03:41:56 - [nodemon] v0.6.5
15 Jan 03:41:56 - [nodemon] watching: /foo/bar/server/src
15 Jan 03:41:56 - [nodemon] running --debug
15 Jan 03:41:56 - [nodemon] starting `coffee --debug --nodejs src/server.coffee`

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^

Error: unrecognized option: --debug
```

Comment: New to node here.  Any details on why nodemon is preferable to supervisor?  One thing I've noticed is that after a crash, there's no frantic attempt at restarting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

actually, it turned out to be a bug :)

The short way:

```
nodemon --debug -w src src/server.coffee
```

Or (where --nodejs and --debug are included as the exec)

```
nodemon -x "coffee --nodejs --debug" -w src src/server.coffee
```

Or (looks nicer than above)

```
nodemon -x coffee --nodejs --debug -w src src/server.coffee
```

(all on nodemon 0.6.6)

Comment: Just for the record, this did not work at the time when I asked this question. It was fixed later. None the less, it is correct now

Answer (score 11):

You can use `--` with supervisor. Not sure if this would work with the `-x` syntax though:

`supervisor -w src -- coffee.js --nodejs --debug src/server.coffee`

Comment: This sort of thing can in fact work with the `--exec`/`-x` syntax. For example, the following worked for me: `supervisor --watch src/index.js --exec serve -- -n -s build`, where `serve`'s arguments come after the `--`.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick review of supervisor, it look like it passes all arguments as arguments to the script itself, so you'll want to use nodemon.

Nodemon picks out it's own arguments, but otherwise they are passed to node. In the current version, arguments after the js/coffee file are preserved, and arguments before the JS file have their order inverted, so try this.

```
nodemon -w src -x coffee --debug --nodejs src/server.coffee
```

Of course, it looks like you noticed that too :P
https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/54

So yeah, the ordering issue is a bug that hopefully will get fixed.

Comment: They aren't passed in the same order, see my latest question update. Thanks

Comment: Updated. Are you going to make a patch? It should be pretty easy, so if aren't let me know and I'll do it.

Comment: I would add that supervisor seems to have [issues](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor/issues/2289) under windows passing arguments correctly